# Press began method in Apple Tv Apps only returning "Select" button event only

Tags: ios, swift, apple-tv

I am trying my hands on Apple TV.

I have implemented this below method however with press on right, left, down, up only "Select" button event is fired.

```
  override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for press in presses {
        switch press.type {
        case .UpArrow:
            print("Up Arrow")
        case .DownArrow:
            print("Down arrow")
        case .LeftArrow:
            print("Left arrow")
        case .RightArrow:
            print("Right arrow")
        case .Select:
            print("Select")
        case .Menu:
            print("Menu")
        case .PlayPause:
            print("Play/Pause")
        }
    }
}
```

How can I find the events here?

Comment: Actually what I want is to get hard press on button event. I know how to use the tap gesture and I am able to implement it. but in some apps... if user press on right button, fastforward happens unless user releases the button. That feature I want to implement.